# merge tow querys in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-outer-join

I have a issuse in sql query.

I have 2 select:

The first one showing:

```
 columnA|columnB
   A    |2
   B    |3
   D    |5
```

The other one showing:

```
columnA|columnC
     A   |1
     B   |5
     C   |7
```

I'm tying to merge this tow query,

this is my query:

```
with 
cte1 as (
select  A,B  from table1 group by A
),
cte2 as (
   select  A,C from table2  group by A
)
select c1.A, c1.B, c2.C
from cte1 c1 left join cte2 c2 
on c2.A = c1.A
order by c1.A asc
```

The problem is when I'm using "`Left join`" the result is :

```
ColumnA|ColumnB|ColumnC
A      |2      |1
B      |3      |5
D      |5      |null
```

It's not showing the value C for the second table,

And whene I'm using "`right join`" the result is :

```
ColumnA|ColumnB|ColumnC
A      |2      |1
B      |3      |5
C      |null   |7
```

It's not showing the value D for the first table,

The result should be like that:

```
 ColumnA|ColumnB|ColumnC
    A      |2      |1
    B      |3      |5
    C      |null   |7
    D      |5      |null
```

any solution please

Comment: This is invalid syntax:  `select  A,B  from table1 group by A`.  Your query will fail in SQL Server and almost any other database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Except for MySQL, SQLite, and probably a couple of other edge cases.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . Happily, no longer true in MySQL.  And for the other edge cases, `A` would need to be the primary key or unique, and aggregation would be superfluous.

Comment: @GordonLinoff whyy ???

Comment: @bfs . . . Why what?

Comment: @GordonLinoff u said that my quety will fail in sql

Comment: @bfs . . . And I thought I explained why:  the aggregation keys are not consistent with the unaggregated `select` columns.

Comment: @GordonLinoff but it's working fine for me

Comment: @bfs . . . Your CTEs as written would fail in SQL Server.  Period.  The group by keys are inconsistent with the `select` columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `full outer join`

```
select coalesce(table1.ColumnA,table2.ColumnA) as ColumnA,
       ColumnB,ColumnC  
from table1 full outer join table2 on table1.ColumnA=table2.ColumnA
```

Comment: yees thank you , i was looking for  full outer join

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a `full join`:

```
with 
    cte1 as (...),
    cte2 as (...)
select coalesce(c1.a, c2.a) a, c1.b, c2.c
from cte1 c1
full join cte2 c2 on c2.a = c1.a
```

Note that the CTEs are not actually needed here, you can use subqueries instead:

```
select coalesce(c1.a, c2.a) a, c1.b, c2.c
from (...) c1
full join (...) c2 on c2.a = c1.a
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a full outer join here:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(t1.A, t2.A) AS A,
    t1.B,
    t2.C
FROM Table1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN t2
    ON t1.A = t2.A;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo